# go to next image element when right arrow is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

So if i had an element like this on HTML
index.html

```
<div><img id="2" src="1.jpg"><img id="2" src="2.jpg"></div>
```

that created by js like this

index.js

```
let image = document.createElement("img")
image.src = img.image
image.style.width = "725"
image.style.height = "1024"
image.setAttribute("id",img.index)
```

how can I make if the right arrow pressed it go to the top of the next image index

I've try this

```
image.onkeydown = function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      if (e.keyCode == '37') {
          document.location.href = `#${img.index--}`
      } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
          document.location.href = `#${img.index++}`
      }
    }
```

but didn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+click+arrow+next+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: keyboard right arrow

Comment: When you change document.location, you load a new page and all code on current page is reloaded

Comment: by the way let image is in forEach so there will be more than 1 image

Comment: Where does img.image come from? Also if you want to stay on the same page, change the hash or just scrollIntoView

Comment: aaa okay, so what is the best way to scroll the image to the next image index ?

Comment: an array of object that have, .image and .index

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the document.location, the script will have to rerun because the page is reloaded. Instead just scrollIntoview:

Also no need for index, you can calculate the index from the content

```js
const imageArr = [
"https://via.placeholder.com/725x1024/000000/FFFFFF/?text=image1",
"https://via.placeholder.com/725x1024/FF0000/0000FF/?text=image2",
"https://via.placeholder.com/725x1024/FFAAFF/00AA00/?text=image3"
]
const container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
container.innerHTML = imageArr.map(img => `<img src="${img}" />`)
const images = container.querySelectorAll("img");
let  current = 0;
const max = imageArr.length

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    return; // Do nothing if event already handled
  }
  const key = event.code;
  if (key === "ArrowLeft") current--;
  else if (key === "ArrowRight") current++
  // wrap 
  if (current < 0) current = max; // change to current=0 if no wrap
  else if (current >= max) current = 0;  // change to current = max if no wrap
  images[current].scrollIntoView()
})
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer"></div>
```